# Find all unique strings in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, unique, text-mining

I am relatively new to R. I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this (one character variable only...my actual df spans 100k+ rows, but for simplicity, let's look at 5 rows only):

```
V1
oximetry, hydrogen peroxide adverse effects, epoprostenol adverse effects
angioedema chemically induced, angioedema chemically induced, oximetry
abo blood group system, imipramine poisoning, adverse effects
isoenzymes, myocardial infarction drug therapy, thrombosis drug therapy
thrombosis drug therapy
```

I want to be able to output every single unique string so that it looks like this:

```
V1
oximetry
hydrogen peroxide adverse effects
epoprostenol adverse effects
angioedema chemically induced
abo blood group system
imipramine poisoning
adverse effects
isoenzymes
myocardial infarction drug therapy
thrombosis drug therapy
```

Do I use the `tm` package? I tried using `dtm` but my code was inefficient since it would convert `dtm` to matrix which would require a lot of memory from 100k+ rows.

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(variable = c(
'oximetry, hydrogen peroxide adverse effects, epoprostenol adverse effects',
'angioedema chemically induced, angioedema chemically induced, oximetry',
'abo blood group system, imipramine poisoning, adverse effects',
'isoenzymes, myocardial infarction drug therapy, thrombosis drug therapy',
'thrombosis drug therapy'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

mutate(df, variable = str_split(variable, ', ')) %>%
  unnest() %>% distinct()
```

Comment: for some reason, the distinct() function didn't work, but your code did give me the output of all strings separated from a comma, so I was able to use another snippet of a code to reduce it down to unique: `unique <- mutate(df, var = str_split(V1, ', ')) %>%
  unnest() %>% distinct();

unique <- subset(unique, !duplicated(var))`

Comment: your code is very fast though, so I'm impressed by `tidyverse` and `stringr`!

Comment: did you try it on your own RStudio as well?

Answer (score 2):

Only using base R, you can use `strsplit()` to split your large string at every "comma+space" or "\n". Then use `unique()` to only return unique strings:

```
text_vec <- c("oximetry, hydrogen peroxide adverse effects, epoprostenol adverse effects
angioedema chemically induced, angioedema chemically induced, oximetry
abo blood group system, imipramine poisoning, adverse effects
isoenzymes, myocardial infarction drug therapy, thrombosis drug therapy
thrombosis drug therapy")

strsplit(text_vec, ", |\\n")[[1]])
# [1] "oximetry"                           "hydrogen peroxide adverse effects" 
# [3] "epoprostenol adverse effects"       "angioedema chemically induced"     
# [5] "angioedema chemically induced"      "oximetry"                          
# [7] "abo blood group system"             "imipramine poisoning"              
# [9] "adverse effects"                    "isoenzymes"                        
# [11] "myocardial infarction drug therapy" "thrombosis drug therapy"           
# [13] "thrombosis drug therapy"   

unique(strsplit(text_vec, ", |\\n")[[1]])
# [1] "oximetry"                           "hydrogen peroxide adverse effects" 
# [3] "epoprostenol adverse effects"       "angioedema chemically induced"     
# [5] "abo blood group system"             "imipramine poisoning"              
# [7] "adverse effects"                    "isoenzymes"                        
# [9] "myocardial infarction drug therapy" "thrombosis drug therapy"
```